# Django get_absolute_url always throwing a 404

Tags: django, templates, url, view

I am building a Django project ( 1.8) and am having trouble using get_absolute_url method of one of my models.  I populated my database with some posts, so I could check my application.  I am able to list the database objects in one of my views, so I know that the objects are there, and my app can display them.  The problem comes when I click a link, and the view always returns a 404 ( basically It can't find an object to display)

Below is most of the code from this app.  I tried to include my imports in these snippets, but truncated some of it to keep the post short.

**valueFact/models.py**

```
class ValueFactPost(models.Model):

STATUS_CHOICE = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published')
)

title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='valueFact_posts') 
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
body = models.TextField()
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                          choices=STATUS_CHOICE,
                          default='draft')

stockSymbol = models.ForeignKey('Symbol', null=True )



objects = models.Manager()
published = ValueFactManager()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('companies:valuefact_detail', args=[self.publish.year,
                                                       self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                                                       self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                                                       self.slug])
```

**urls.py**

```
 from django.conf.urls import include, url
urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^companies/', include('valueFact.urls', namespace='companies', app_name='companies')),

]
```

**valueFact/urls.py**

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', views.valueFactListView.as_view(), name='valueFact_list'),
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
    views.valuefact_detail,
    name='valuefact_detail'),
```

]

**valueFact/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from valueFact.models import ValueFactPost, Symbol

class valueFactListView(ListView):
    queryset = ValueFactPost.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'valueFacts'
    paginate_by = 2
    template_name = 'companies/valueFact/list.html'


def valuefact_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(ValueFactPost, slug=post,
                             status='published',
                             publish__year=year,
                             publish__month=month,
                             publish__day=day)
    return render(request, 'companies/valuefact/detail.html', {'post':post})
```

The template where the problem seems to occur:

**list.html**

```
    {% for post in valueFacts %}
    <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">

        {{ post.title}}
    </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="date">
        Published {{post.publish}} by {{post.author}}
    </p>
    {{post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks}}
    {% endfor %}**
```

The error in the django console is : Not Found: /companies/2016/03/23/seadrill-debt/

I have spent an inordinate amount of time on this issue which would probably take someone a couple of minutes to fix.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Attempting to use the admin site to view the object on my website also threw a 404 error

Comment: Your `get_absolute_url` method is passing arguments to `reverse`, but your url pattern used *keyword* arguments.

Comment: I ended up changing the get_absolute_url function to NOT take the month, year and day and this ended up working.  My syntax for those arguements are probably an error, or my model doesn't recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have PYTZ installed? I can't guarantee this is the answer, but it's worth a try. I don't see anything wrong with the code, as I'm using pretty much the same code in a project.

Comment: Yes sir.  It was one of the first things I did before I set out to make my models.

Answer (score 0):

If you use different timezone than UTC, when an object is saved, `publish` attribute can be different than when you have UTC timezone.

If that's the case your get_absolute_url method has to return `localtime` version of `publish`.

In your `models.py`, consider writing like this

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """
        Get single object.
        year, month, day, and slug order.
        """
        # convert to Asia/seoul time
        localdatetime = timezone.localtime(self.publish)
        return reverse(
            "blog:post_detail",
            args=[
                localdatetime.year,
                localdatetime.month,
                localdatetime.day,
                self.slug,
            ],
        )
```

SO has [other similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285454/django-get-object-or-404-with-datetimefield) regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**
Instead of using `DateTimeField` use `DateField` in your model and the problem will be solved.

```py
# models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    publish = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

**Method 2:** Override `get_object`

Answer (score -1):

Your url pattern establishes 4 keyword arguments:

- year
- month
- day
- post

but your call to `reverse` is passing those values in as *positional* arguments (args), which is a list. Instead, pass them in as *keyword* arguments (kwargs), which is a dictionary:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('companies:valuefact_detail', args=[],
        kwargs={
            'year':self.publish.year,
            'month': self.publish.strftime('%m'),
            'day': self.publish.strftime('%d'),
            'post': self.slug
        })
```

Comment: I attempted to use the keyword arguments (kwargs) vs the positional arguments (args), and I was still getting the 404.  FYI I did not put in the downvote.

Comment: The `kwargs` change is definitely required. If that's not working, check that you're able to call reverse through a unit test, or just by hand by returning an object from the ORM and checking that the method returns a value. It could be that one of the values doesn't match the pattern, or it could also be that there is another URL pattern that is unintentionally stepping on this one.

Comment: Sadly I have tried about 4 variants of code and am still getting 404s for trying to get the object.  It doesn't seem to matter if I am using args, or kwargs.   I checked other URL patterns, and I can't see any problems there ( I only have the URL conf file and the one listed here.   I checked hand coding the ORM and my get_absolute_url was returning nothing, giving the same error as before.

Comment: Try changing the view to just retrieve the object and not use `get_object_or_404`. That takes out one automated behavior and may reveal why the view is failing to return the object.

Comment: Every different attempt results in this type of error :  Reverse for 'valuefact_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 2}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []    .  It doesnt even seem to matter what the arguements are, it always finds no patterns to match.

Comment: Something is passing incorrect keyword arguments to the function. Your code is expecting 4 keyword arguments, not one. There are no patterns in your example that would match, since none are expecting `pk: 2`

Comment: My appologies, I should have specified that the above comment was one of many attempts at trying different url patterns,  the original code didn't use primary keys, just what was listed.  Given what I have tried over the past week, I think this might go beyond the get_abolsute_url function, the view, and the url patterns..

Comment: For a final follow up, I took your advice in using the shell to determine if my view function was returning anything.   I had to eliminate some of the url parameters since my view function would not return anything while using them.  I ended up keeping the slug, and published year, and was able to make it work.

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like the values for month and day are getting munged somehow. That at least gets you a place to start testing.