# Django get_object_or_404() with DateTimeField

Tags: django, sqlite, timezone

I'm now reading the book "Django by Example".

I have a problem when looking up the record with parameters.

My codes are as shown below:

settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'
```

models.py

```
    ...
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    ...
```

views.py

```
def post_show(request, year, month, day, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,
                         slug=slug,
                         status='published',
                         published__year=year,
                         published__month=month,
                         published__day=day)

return render(request, 'blog/default/post/show.html', {'post': post})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    views.post_show, name='post_show'),
```

MVT works fine, but I believe that there's something wrong with DateTimeField, TimeZone or SQLite3.

In SQLite3, "published" DateTimeField has the value: "2016-05-17 19:57:03" which is UTC time. I'm in Asia/Seoul ahead of 9 hours. so I actually posted at 4:57 am on May 18th.

```
>>> p = get_object_or_404(Post,slug='test', published__year=2016, published__month=5, published__day=18)
>>> p.title
'test'
>>> p.published
datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 17, 19, 57, 3, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

DB says it's published on 17th, but I have to pass the parameter "18". If I pass 17, it thrwos 404.

How can I force filter condition to use UTC timezone?

Answer (score 4):

I answer my post by myself. I read the manual which says.

> When USE_TZ is True, datetime fields are converted to the current time zone before filtering.

I changed get_absolute_url() method to convert the UTC to Asia/Seoul timezone:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):

    # this line was added.
    published_localtime = timezone.localtime(self.published)

    return reverse('blog:post_show',
                   args=[
                       published_localtime.year,
                       published_localtime.strftime('%m'),
                       published_localtime.strftime('%d'),
                       self.slug
```

I fixed it like this, but I'd like to know the better way if I've got. Thank you.