# Django 404 Error Raised by: blog.views.post_detail

Tags: python, django-urls

***Hello, Everyone***

I'm a novice programmer trying to follow Antonio Mele tutorial on blog creation using django.

Am stuck with the post/detail.html which is not responding
below are the codes.Kindly help.

Problem: Am unable to view details of the post

**404 Error: Page not found**

Page not found (404)

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2020/3/13/more-post/

Raised by:  blog.views.post_detail

No Post matches the given query.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

**Error:Page not found**

Page not found (404)

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
    1.admin/

    2.blog/
```

The empty path didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.*

[urls.py/blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMCZP.png)

[urls.py/mysite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBeSx.png)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUcDu.png)

**urls.py/blog**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlspatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/', 
        views.post_detail, 
        name='post_detail'),
```

]

**urls.py/mysite**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
```

]

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/list.html',
                  {'posts':posts})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post, 
                                   status='published',
                                   publish__year=year, 
                                   publish__month=month, 
                                   publish__day=day)
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/detail.html', 
                  {'post': post})
```

Comment: Have you created `fourth-post`? What is output of `blogs/`? Also, please paste the actual code and error stacktrace here, instead of screenshots of code.

Comment: pls add the content of your links to the Q, not as external links

Comment: welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. And your issue is very certainly not an issue, just that no post matches your request.

Comment: Hello, I've tried to add more details to the question,kindly assist

Comment: @stackoverflowusrone Yes,i created the fourth-post, blog/ output is page not found

Comment: The error you added means that you tried a worong URL `/` which is not included in your project URLs; you have `admin/`and `blog/` in mysite urlpatterns. Add the full error for `/blog` url as well

Comment: Did you check that the post exist? Try to run `get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post, 
                                   status='published',
                                   publish__year=year, 
                                   publish__month=month, 
                                   publish__day=day)` in a python console and see what happens

Comment: @LiorPollak Hello,when run the code i get an error of "No such file or directory"."C:\Users\Fred 69\Projects\mysite>"C:/Users/Fred 69/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe" replinput
C:/Users/Fred 69/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe: can't open file 'replinput': [Errno
2] No such file or directory"

Comment: Seems like your python installation is messed. Try to reinstall python

Comment: Hello, Pollak am still getting the same response.

Comment: You made a mistake in your views.py. In views.py, Antonio Mele wrote that posts = Post.published.all() and not that posts = Post.objects.all(). Because you'll never display drafts on the main page.

Answer (score 1):

Someone had the same problem with the previous version of the book, asked here and published his solution (there must be a much more elegant way), have a look here:
[Django get_object_or_404() with DateTimeField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285454/django-get-object-or-404-with-datetimefield)

In addition, use the shell to debug items, you should have seen that the date in DB is recorded in UTC:

```
>>> post = Post.objects.get(title__startswith='who')
>>> post.publish
datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 18, 1, 18, 56, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the admin area, where the articles have a 'draft' status. Change them to 'published' status. In the views.py in the function post_list(), change the output of posts on a page with only the status published:

```
def post_list(request):    
    posts = Post.objects.filter(status='published')
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

In this case, articles with only the status published are displayed on the posts page. By clicking on the article link, you should be transferred to a full post without error.

Comment: @Fred69-coder made an error, draft posts shouldn't be in the posts queryset in the post_list view. The error is related to timezones, not the status of the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
#FOLLOW THIS PROCEDURE.I HOPE IT HELPS YOU OR ANY ONE ELSE IN THE FUTURE

#blog/models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


 class Post(models.Model):
    published = models.BooleanField(True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=timezone.now)

# At blog/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import (post_list, post_detail)


urlspatterns = [
    path('', post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('<str:slug>/', post_detail, name='post_detail'),


#At mysite/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),

#At blog/views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published) 
    template_name = blog/post_list.html
    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, template_name, context)

def post_detail(request, slug):
    posts = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    template_name = blog/post_detail.html
    context = {'posts':posts}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


# At the template/blog/post_list.html
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article>
            <div>      
                <small>{{ post.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                <h2><a href="{{ post.slug }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p >{{ post.body }}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}


# At template/blog/post_detail.html
<article>
    <div>
        <small>{{ posts.created_on|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>     
        <h2>{{ posts.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ posts.body }}</p>
    </div>
</article>
```

#The above code should fix the the issue properly.